# ios fb graph api search for places with app or usertoken?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-ios-sdk

my app used to have the following fb api graph query (original query) with fb sdk for ios (version 3.1) :

```c
NSString *fbquery =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"search?type=place&center=48.8567,2.3508&distance=1000&limit=40&fields=picture.width(200),cover];
```

This does not work anymore. I checked the docs and figured out that it works with appending a app access token. This works well with the following query within fb sdk for ios (version 3.5.3):

```c
NSString *fbquery =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"search?type=place&center=48.8567,2.3508&distance=1000&limit=40&fields=picture,cover&access_token=%@", appDelegate.session.accessTokenData.accessToken];
```

Result of the query:

```js
{
    data =     (
                {
            id = 165207683494457;
            picture =             {
                data =                 {
                    "is_silhouette" = 0;
                    url = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/276836_165207683494457_49288222_q.jpg";
                };
            };
        },
                {
            id = 151161104922563;
            ...
            ...
```

But when I try to specify the picture width which I want to retrieve, like in the original query: `picture.width(200)` then I get an error:

```js
  {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 1;
            message = "An unknown error has occurred.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 500;
   }, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=500}
```

The [fb developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/) state:

> - Searches across **page** and **place** objects requires an **app access token**.
> - All other endpoints require a user access token.

I use already the app access token so it should work, but it does not.

What should I do? Where is the issue?

My suggestion would be to try with a user access token, but how do I retrieve this from the `appDelegate.session`? Could not find the user access token there.

I use now (as above stated the fb sdk for ios in version 3.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook graph API are changing and now there is a smarter way to get pictures if you know the picture id

you can use this url to get redirected to the url of the image with the wanted resolution:

```
@"https://graph.facebook.com/%llu/picture?width=256&height=256&access_token=%@"
```

where %llu is the place of the picture id and %@ is the fb token

so your fql request could be smaller and you can compose the url dynamically depending to the resolution that you need

Comment: from the picture I have just the direct url. I have the id of the whole element (see ajax-code), does this id apply as well for the picture retrieving?
Furthermore I want at the search already only pictures with a width of 200px. Getting the picture id and seeing at the second request that the width is not available would be unnecessary.